# What is the difference between SQL Server 2012 Express versions?

Tags: sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2008-express

I've come across this page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 and I am a bit confused about the different versions here.

So I would like to know what is the difference between

- `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe`
- `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe`
- `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe`

Comment: I have been amazed by the lack of usability with these MS downloads. Why haven't they fixed it?

Comment: I am amazed we still need StackOverflow to figure out this download pages, and this was asked in 2012.

Comment: Not as bad as the Java installer pages.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Scroll down on that page and you'll see:

> *Express **with Tools** (with LocalDB) Includes the database engine and SQL Server Management Studio Express)*
>   This package contains everything needed to install and configure SQL Server as a database server. Choose either LocalDB or Express depending on your needs above.

That's the `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` download....  (**WT** = with tools)

---

> *Express with **Advanced Services*** (contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search)
>   This package contains all the components of SQL Express. This is a larger download than “with Tools,” as it also includes both Full Text Search and Reporting Services.

That's the `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` download ...  (**ADV** = Advanced Services)

---

The `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` file is just the database engine - no tools, no Reporting Services, no fulltext-search - just barebones engine.

Comment: It appears to me then that SQL Server Express Advanced has *everything*, SQL Server Express With Tools has the tools (and nothing more) and SQL Server Express plain is just the database engine. Correct me if I'm wrong here...

Comment: @Shrout1: **Express** = just the engine; **Express with Tools** = engine + mgmt studio; **Express with advanced services** = engine, mgmt studio, additional features (fulltext search, reporting services, integration services, SQL Server Data Tools etc.) - that's basically what I said - or don't you agree?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :) It was just the order that it was stated; I wasn't sure if one was inclusive of the other or not. And they *say* there's no such thing as a stupid question, though that might not be the case here on stack... lol.

Comment: Always look to download the Management Studio as well. Makes development much easier.

Answer (score 67):

[This link goes to the best comparison chart around](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx), directly from the Microsoft. It compares ALL aspects of all MS SQL server editions. To compare three editions you are asking about, just focus on the last three columns of every table in there.

**Summary** compiled from the above document:

```
    * = contains the feature
                                           SQLEXPR    SQLEXPRWT   SQLEXPRADV
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    > SQL Server Core                         *           *           *
    > SQL Server Management Studio            -           *           *
    > Distributed Replay – Admin Tool         -           *           *
    > LocalDB                                 -           *           *
    > SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)            -           -           *
    > Full-text and semantic search           -           -           *
    > Specification of language in query      -           -           *
    > some of Reporting services features     -           -           *
```

Comment: Comparison charts like this should be basically in the same page as the download page that you need to choose and have no idea. Cheers

Comment: it used to be like that, now there are no more technicalities :D