# How to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio using silent installation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, wix, bootstrapper

When I try to install SQL Server 2008 R2 using installCommand in ExePackage, it's installed  Configuration Tools only, but I need to install SQL Server Management Studio also, This is my install Command

> "InstallCommand =" /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=CustomName
>   /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true
>   /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic
>   /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1 /INDICATEPROGRESS=FALSE
>   /HIDECONSOLE"

Please help, I don't know what to do to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio in silent mode?

Comment: /Q http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Comment: can't we install sql server 2008 R2 management studio using /QS?

Comment: InstallCommand =" /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=CustomName /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SAPWD=&quot;test@123&quot; /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM&quot; /TCPENABLED=1 /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /INDICATEPROGRESS=FALSE /HIDECONSOLE" By using above install command sql server installed, but not sql server management studio, Here "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log" summary details-> Detailed Results, Feature : SQL Status: Skipped, Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What is the difference between SQL Server 2012 Express versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170215/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-server-2012-express-versions)

from mentioned link, I come to know /FEATURES=SQL,AS,RS,IS,Tools will work only in SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe (advanced version) not in SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe Thank You.